# Generate Form Fields for each Record in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-forms

I have https://stackblitz.com/edit/ingecalc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
  paramsFormArray: FormArray;  
  properties: Record<string, number> = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paramsFormArray = this.fb.group(
      this.properties,
    );
  }
```

Now I want that for each `property` in `properties` to have an `input` in the HTML.

```
a = [1   ]
b = [2   ]
c = ...
d = ...
```

However it does not work. I tried also "array" instead of "group" does not work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of things going wrong. So Ill give my level best to explain, please ask any doubts if you have any.

1. Calculator needs to be a service ( basically the same as class, but is accessible through constructor, like how you did, class cannot be accessed through constructor ( through Dependency Injection)
2. Form Group needs to be initialized and we can subscribe to an observable of formgroup called `valueChanges` this will trigger whenever the value gets changed.
3. In HTML we can wrap the controls inside a form and add the attribute `[formGroup]="formGroup"` this will map the created form group to the controls set in HTML.
4. we do not need `ngModel` or `keyDown` since we subscribe to the changes!

component details

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CalculatorService } from './calculator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  debounceTime = 500;

  paramsFormGroup: FormGroup;
  properties: any = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: 0 };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private calculator: CalculatorService) {
    this.paramsFormGroup = this.fb.group(this.properties);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.functionToBeCalled();
    this.subscription.add(
      this.paramsFormGroup.valueChanges
        .pipe(debounceTime(this.debounceTime))
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.functionToBeCalled();
        })
    );
  }

  getControlLabel(type: string) {
    console.log(this.paramsFormGroup && this.paramsFormGroup.controls, type);
    if (
      this.paramsFormGroup &&
      this.paramsFormGroup.controls &&
      this.paramsFormGroup.controls[type]
    ) {
      return this.paramsFormGroup.controls[type].value;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  functionToBeCalled() {
    const { a, b } = this.paramsFormGroup.value;
    const newProperties = this.calculator.calculate({ a, b });
    this.paramsFormGroup.patchValue(newProperties);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

service details

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { C } from './calculator/c';
import { D } from './calculator/d';

@Injectable()
export class CalculatorService {
  constructor() {}

  calculate(properties: Record<string, number>) {
    const a = properties['a'];
    const b = properties['b'];

    const c = C(a, b);
    const d = D(a, b);

    properties['c'] = c;
    properties['d'] = d;
    return properties;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ingecalc-ywsah4)